# How to use kubectl to check the containers/pods of an application are spread to different AZs in an AWS EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to see how the containers of an application are distributed/spread in the cluster. Which command can be used to find it out? I want to check if the containers are all running in the same AZ.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74603567/6309601 provides working command to get the results,  not sure why you asked same question  multiple times

Comment: Another one is to find the config/settings of a cluster. This one is about a particular service/application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kubectl with custom-columns to get any custom output. So it depends on which status data (if any) EKS enrich the pod with. I would recommend to check if it sets any EKS specific labels or annotations.

I can provide an example of custom-columns so you get the idea of how to use it:

```bash
kubectl get pods -A -o custom-columns='NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,REQUESTS_CPU:.spec.containers[*].resources.requests.cpu,REQUESTS_MEMORY:.spec.containers[*].resources.requests.memory,LIMIT_CPU:.spec.containers[*].resources.limits.cpu,LiMIT_MEMORY:.spec.containers[*].resources.limits.memory'
```

That command will show you all pods on your cluster and how its CPU and memory requests are set:

```bash
NAMESPACE       NAME                                       REQUESTS_CPU   REQUESTS_MEMORY   LIMIT_CPU   LiMIT_MEMORY
cattle-system   rancher-7c676f75c-29jrz                    <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
cattle-system   rancher-7c676f75c-dz4k4                    <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
cattle-system   rancher-7c676f75c-hzs5q                    <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-646c67487-8j4wz               <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-cainjector-7cb8669d6b-sxklw   <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
cert-manager    cert-manager-webhook-696c5db7ff-vzjdl      <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-create-mt4cb       <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-patch-99p6p        <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-5dpjh             <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
kube-system     coredns-59499769fb-4m6m2                   100m           70Mi              <none>      170Mi
kube-system     coredns-autoscaler-67cbd4599c-7ld97        20m            10Mi              <none>      <none>
kube-system     kube-flannel-5fgzm                         100m           50Mi              100m        50Mi
kube-system     metrics-server-585b7cc746-bzksn            100m           200Mi             <none>      <none>
kube-system     rke-coredns-addon-deploy-job-jjj4k         <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
kube-system     rke-ingress-controller-deploy-job-htrkn    <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
kube-system     rke-metrics-addon-deploy-job-fqzpd         <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
kube-system     rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-kffmk        <none>         <none>            <none>      <none>
```

In order to figure out which data is available that you can include in your custom columns, I would recommend to get one pod, and show it as YAML, like

```bash
kubectl get pod -n kube-system coredns-59499769fb-4m6m2 -o yaml
```

When you look at that YAML, you will be able to find out how to reference your custom-column output.

Answer (score 0):

For every service kubernetes creates a corresponding endpoints resource that contains the IP addresses of the pods.
You can use

```
kubectl describe endpoints <service-name>
```

To find out those IPs. Then you could look to which subnets they belong.

If you want to have your pods distributed among your AZs, have a look at pod topology spread constraints:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/