# How to describe a Kubernetes cluster using kubectl?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to check the Kubernetes configuration - how many nodes, etc. I tried the following command.

```
kubectl describe cluster
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "cluster"
```

BTW, I tried to use the following command to check the AZ of the nodes of the pods. But it returns `<none>` for all the pods' nodes.

```
kubectl get pods -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,ZONE:.metadata.labels.'topology\.Kubernetes\.io/zone'
```

How to use `kubectl` to find the AZs of the pods?

Comment: `kubectl get pods -o wide` returns `NAME, READY, STATUS, RESTARTS, AGE, IP, NODE, NOMINATED NODE, READINESS GATES` only.

Comment: Seems like the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74557664/how-to-use-kubectl-to-check-the-containers-pods-of-an-application-are-spread-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my nodes showing zone info(made up) in the cluster:

```
kubectl get node -Ltopology.kubernetes.io/zone
NAME                            STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION   ZONE
development-kube-controller-1   Ready    control-plane   48d   v1.24.6   zone
development-kube-worker-1       Ready    <none>          48d   v1.24.6   zone-A
development-kube-worker-2       Ready    <none>          48d   v1.24.6   zone-B
```

Using the `awk` command, the label `topology.kubernetes.io/zone` is merged with the name of the pods scheduled on that particular node.

**NOTE**: I have used lowercase `k` in the label key `topology\.kubernetes\.io/zone`; however, in your case, it's uppercase `K` in the question. You might want to calibrate your command.

```
kubectl describe  node |awk '/topology.kubernetes.io\/zone/{zone=$1;next} /^  Namespace/{flag=1; getline; next} /^Allocated resources:/{flag=0} flag{print  $2, zone}' |column -t
calico-node-swz7j                                      topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone
coredns-74d6c5659f-4mpcp                               topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone
dns-autoscaler-59b8867c86-w4dls                        topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone       
kubernetes-dashboard-648989c4b4-b4k7h                  topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-A
kubernetes-metrics-scraper-84bbbc8b75-x72pf            topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-A
nginx-proxy-development-kube-worker-1                  topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-A
nodelocaldns-xt6hr                                     topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-A
metallb-controller-94c85f6db-6j8j5                     topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-A
metallb-speaker-4fz99                                  topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-A
argocd-application-controller-0                        topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-B
argocd-applicationset-controller-5bff759d68-kk7tx      topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-B
argocd-dex-server-59c59b5d96-7z7th                     topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-B
argocd-notifications-controller-6df97c8577-26z9m       topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-B
argocd-redis-684fb8c6dd-bxb25                          topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-B
argocd-repo-server-79d8c5f7b4-fnh7g                    topology.kubernetes.io/zone=zone-B
```

PS: You can print `$1` in the `awk` command to print the namespace, in case of filtering based on namespace is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I could be missing the point of your question, but if you just need the nodes, you could do

`kubectl get nodes`

and then

`kubectl describe node {node-name}`

to get further details of an individual node

You could also combine the output from `kubectl get nodes` and either use `jsonpath` or `jq` to filter the information you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command

```
kubectl cluster-info
```